# how to get Linux to automatically release old pagecache pages?

Tags: linux, caching

Ever since upgrading to Linux kernel 5.8 and later, I've been having problems with my system freezing up from running out of RAM, and it's all going to the pagecache.

I have a program that reorganizes the data from the OpenStreetMap planet_latest.osm.pbf file into a structure that's more efficient for my usage. However, because this file is larger than the amount of RAM on my system (60GB file versus 48GB RAM), the page cache fills up. Before kernel 5.8, the cache would reach full, and then keep chugging along (with an increase in disk thrashing). Since 5.8, the system freezes because it won't ever automatically release a page from the page cache (such as 30GB earlier in my sequential read of the planet_latest.osm.pbf file). I don't need to use my reorganizing program to hang the system; I found the following unprivileged command would do it:

cat planet_latest.osm.pbf >/dev/null

I have tried using the fadvise64() system service to manually force releases of pages in the planet file I have already passed; it helps, but doesn't entirely solve the problem with the various output files my program creates (especially when those temporary output files are randomly read back later).

So, what does it take to get the 5.8 through 5.10 Linux kernel to actually automatically release old pages from the page cache when system RAM gets low?

To work around the problem, I have been using a script to monitor cache size and write to /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches when the cache gets too large, but of course that also releases new pages I am currently using along with obsolete pages.

```
while true ; do
    H=`free | head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $6}'`
    if [ $H -gt 35000000 ]; then
        echo -n $H " @ " ; date
        echo 1 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
        sensors | grep '°C'
        H=`free | head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $6}'`
        echo -n $H " @ "; date
    fi
    sleep 30
done
```

(the sensors stuff is to watch out for CPU overheating in stages of my program that are multi-threaded CPU-intensive rather than disk-intensive).

I have filed a bug report at kernel.org, but they haven't looked at it yet.

Comment: Obviously this is not a general problem. Linux 5.8+ does not normally crash when reading medium-large files from disk. Have you tried a memtest and disabling any swap/zram/bcache that could interfere?

Comment: It doesn't crash, it hangs, because the kernel philosophy is apparently "pagecache is more important than running programs", so it swaps everything out to allow the cache to keep growing, until the system doesn't do anything because no processes are still in RAM.

Comment: I'm not sure if something broke in kernel 5.8, because it didn't use to behave this way; the cache would grow until minimum free memory was left, and stay at that size. It doesn't seem to be releasing "old" entries in the pagecache any more. Note that I have been optimizing my program for years to make it run faster, while OpenStreetMap has been enlarging their database, but it wasn't until that kernel upgrade that the system started hanging from excessive swapouts.

Comment: If you're right, this is an extremely serious regression that makes any system running e.g. Ubuntu 20.10 or Fedora 33 practically unusable. You'll be relieved to know that I'm unable to reproduce this issue on my machine running 5.8.0 though.

Comment: You can't reproduce it with a single file larger than the system RAM and the cp to /dev/null command? I was wondering if the problem was happening simply because I sped up my program so much that the timer for "least recently used" never timed out any more. But it had to be a kernel behavior change because my application optimizations over that kernel change were very small.

Comment: FYI, my current system is Fedora 32 with kernel 5.10.19-100.fc32.x86_64, and I ran into the same problem downloading the latest planet-yymmdd.osm.pbf file, just from writing that file to disk with the wget command.

Comment: My guess is that the problem is mostly related to your machine (bad ram, bad disk, loose connection etc). Yours is that Linux is no longer compatible with the 99% of machines that have more disk than RAM. By Occam's razor, I think it makes sense to try to rule out the former first.

Comment: @Andrew I could not reproduce a hang on a (Debian) 5.10.5 kernel using `pv several big files altogether larger than my RAM+swap > /dev/null`. However, my system is probably not under the same workload. Can you try with swap disabled if enabled? I also suggest you check the content of `/proc/pressure/*` right after hanging. Lastly, if you are familiar with kernel compilation, you may take the two closest kernel versions behaving differently and `git bisect` kernels until you find the commit introducing the unwanted behavior. It could be helpful for kernel devs going through your bug report.

Comment: Hmmm... not sure if having separate files would make a difference (could one be freed from the cache while working the second?). However, I tried copying the huge file to another Fedora 32 system I have (with much less RAM), and it survived and behaved as expected (even though the sending system still needed manual cache flushes to survive). So the one larger system must have some kind of hardware glitch that memtest86+ didn't detect.

Comment: Surely the balance between cache and swap paging is set by /proc/sys/vm/swappiness.  Also help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq (section 8)

Comment: I have long since tried swappiness=0, and it still didn't solve the problem. And the other system I mentioned one comment earlier still killed the X-windows environment so I lost my graphical console; good thing I had already created an SSH terminal login as a backup. So swappiness=0 doesn't seem to protect from the OOM killer or from the eagerness of the filesystem cache to grow.